# Only one instance of entire app multiple activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, single-instance

I have an Android app with 3 activities. I basically want to have one instance that encompasses all three Activities.

So for Activities A, B, and C, I would only want the user to be able to looking at one of those at a time. I do not want multiple instances of any of these activities. I have tried `android:launchMode="singleTask"` which sort of works in a way, but when the user returns to the app, it always launches Activity A again first instead of going to Activity B, where the user pressed the home button.

Would it be best for me to just moved all the Fragments hosted by these activities into one activity and do away with Activities B and C? Activity A hosts only one fragment, a login/signup page.

Using `singleTask launch mode` do I need to still add `Intent` flags when starting other activities?

Answer (score 0):

> So for Activities A, B, and C, I would only want the user to be able
>   to looking at one of those at a time.

You can only have one `Activity` on focus at the time. Another `Activity` might be visible behind your `Activity` (i.e. the top most `Activity` might be themed as a `Dialog`), but only one `Activity` has focus; hence the user can only interact with one `Activity` at the time.

> it always launches Activity A again first instead of going to Activity
>   B

Android will always launch first the `Activity` that is labeled as

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml. You can add logic to create the illusion that this `Activity` was not called, and you launch an `Intent` to the corresponding one.

> Would it be best for me to just moved all the Fragments hosted by
>   these activities into one activity and do away with Activities B and
>   C?

That is entirely up to you. In my opinion, it might feel more proper to use `Fragments` since you can easily replace them based on logical conditions (i.e. logged in or not) without having to create a new `Activity` (it might seem more seamless to the user).

Answer (score 0):

you should use three fragments using ViewPager instead of using three activitiew.

Comment: there are libraries which will simplify the use of multiple fragments in a single activity. if you need help..I can suggest you the Library ViewPagers..and sample code how to use them